# Constructing an isomorphism between vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, noncommutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a central simple $k$-algebra of dimension $n^2$ over $k$. Also assume that $A= {\rm End} (V)$, where $V$ is an $n$-dimensional $k$-vector space. For $0\leq i \leq n$, let $M_i$ be the set of matrices with arbitrary entries on the $i^{\rm th}$ column and zero in other columns. These are the left simple $A$-modules, and they are isomorphic. Also assume that $B= {\rm End} (W)$, where $W$ is an $n$-dimensional $k$-vector space. Also suppose that we have given an algebra homomorphism $\varphi: A \rightarrow B$. I am stuck and I can not realize how should I construct an isomorphism $f : V \rightarrow W$.

What can we say about the reverse procedure? Given the isomorphism $f : V \rightarrow W$, how should I construct the algebra homomorphism $\varphi: A \rightarrow B$?

Comment: What is an algebra isomorphism? It is an isomorphism of the underlying vector spaces respecting the algebra product? Then we are done.

Comment: If $f : V \to W$ is an isomorphism then it induces an isomorphism $\text{End}(V) \ni X \mapsto fXf^{-1} \in \text{End}(W)$ (with inverse $Y \mapsto f^{-1} Y f$). This is a standard "transport of structure" deal.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you so much for your very clear and fruitful comment. If I am not mistaken, your point also proves the Skolem–Noether theorem for $k$-algebra morphisms from End$(V)$ to End$(W)$. Fixing $f: V \rightarrow W$, then it is easy to show that every isomorphism from $V$ to $W$, is of the form $g \circ f$, where $0\neq g \in End(W)$. Now it suffices just to notice that every $k$-algebra morphism from End$(V)$ to End$(W)$ is induced by an isomorphism from $V$ to $W$. Hope I am not mistaken. Thanks for your enlightening comment.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan But yet I can not realize how should I construct an isomorphism $f: V \rightarrow W$, from the algebra homomorphism $\varphi: End(V) \rightarrow End(W)$?

Comment: @Neo: no, I've only proven the easy direction, it takes more work to prove Skolem-Noether. In the other direction you can argue as follows: given an isomorphism $f : \text{End}(V) \cong \text{End}(W)$, the pullback $f^{\ast}(W)$ of $W$ must be a simple $\text{End}(V)$-module, so must be isomorphic to $V$ (which is the unique simple $\text{End}(V)$-module). You can use this to write down an isomorphism $V \cong W$.